# Questions About Hawaiian Earring and Properties

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, path-connected

I've read a bit about the Hawaiian earring and some of its properties. I have a few questions that I haven't been able to find online or derive myself.

1. How would we prove that the Hawaiian earring is connected.
2. I'm not too familiar with the different types of connectedness. I've only learned about connectedness (with open disjoint separations) and path connectedness. Is the Hawaiian earring path-connected?
3. Is there a homeomorphism between the entire Hawaiian earring and the half with only the circles with centers on positive x values?

Edit: I had a slight misunderstanding about the earring but that's been clarified in the comments so 1 and 2 are no longer necessary. I am still curious about number 3, though.

Comment: We can immediately see that it's path connected by showing that given two points $x,y \in \mathbb{H}$, we can travel along the circle $x$ lies on to get to the origin and then depart from here onto the circle $y$ lies on, so it's path-connected. In fact, it's locally path connected.

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by the last question.

Comment: Oh, that's true. I think I had a slight misunderstanding thinking that $(0,0)$ was excluded. The main question is number 3 then. I'll edit the question to reflect that.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question 3 (depends on how exactly you define the Hawaiian earring), but the Hawaiian earring is composed of countable number of circles with a single common point. The choice of circles is irrelevant (up to homeomorphism), as long as these two properties are satisfied.

Comment: "The half with only the circles with centers on positive $x" values" - so what is your definition of the entire Hawaiian earring?